# How can i conclude that inclusion of a variable/set of variables improves my prediction using LASSO regression?

Tags: r, regression, prediction, lasso

I am building a multiple linear regression model to predict a continuous outcome from a total of 9 variables (2x continous, 7x categorical).

The rationale is that 6 categorical variables were so far not assessed this context. My aim is to show that inclusion of these variables (or at least one of those) improves my prediction and thus are clinical significanct.

A LASSO regression model was trained using 10-fold cross-validation in a training data set (80%) using the method=glmnet and the caret package in R.

When the trained model is applied to the test data, similar R2 and RMSE are obtained. This leads me to the conclusion that the model works.

However, i am stuck on the problem that my aim is to show that these variable improve my predicion.

Comment: That's a small set of independent variables.  Why use LASSO?  How many observations do you have?  With 9 total predictors you could exhaustively test all subsets and use a model selection criterion like AIC to pick the best one.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. LASSO is used to get rid of irrelevant predictors and also possible collinearity between them, n=80. How could i test all subsets? Do you suggest to build 9 different models (one per predictor) and use AIC one those? Would this approach be somewhat similar to stepwise regression?

Comment: I'm suggesting all subsets of the nine variables.  That means each one alone, all pairs, all sets of three, etc.  That would give a total of $2^9-1=511$ different models.  It's not stepwise regression because it tests exhaustively and uses AIC to pick the best option.